# DataStudio chart failing on initial page load in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, looker-studio

I have embedded a DataStudio chart on a page using an iframe. It loads without error in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE 11 it fails on initial load (it will load on refresh) and gives this message: "We're sorry! Data Studio is not available right now. Please try again later.".

I can't find any reference to this message that matches the behaviour. Is there any known problems on IE11 with DataStudio? Any other trouble-shooting methods to see what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to reproduce the issue with IE 11 browser and I am able to produce the issue.

I noticed that Data of the chart is displaying but chart is not displaying. You can notice that options for charts are also there.

[image]

Other thing I noticed that there is an error in the console.

[image]

I tried to configure some IE options and settings but it did not made any difference in the result.

I suggest you to keep similar security settings level for all security zones and test on your side.

I try to find the browser support related information in Google Data Studio documentation but I did not got relevant information.

While using the Google Data Studio, I noticed that it is not rendering and working properly with IE as it works with Chrome browser.

In my search, I found that many other users has similar question which was posted on their support forum.

1. [Charts not displayed in Microsoft Edge/IE](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/9269345?hl=en)
2. [Unable to visualize some google data studio charts in Internet
   explorer... does it supports IE?](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/9173369?hl=en)
3. [Data Studio issue on Internet Explorer](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/18715046?hl=en)

At present, Based on user experience. It looks like Google Data studio is not fully compatible with IE and Edge browser.

I suggest you to raise a question about IE support on their official forum.

[Welcome to the Data Studio Help Community](https://support.google.com/datastudio/community?hl=en)